# Uncaught TypeError: Property ... is not a function - after page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm using a cross-domain Ajax request to an external API. Every so often it fails, with the console message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'photos' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

Looking at the JSON being returned, it is valid JSON, so it is not the fault of the external API.

I can't reproduce the error reliably: the only factor that seems to trigger the error is when I call the request quickly and repeatedly.

In this case I'm calling the Ajax request when the user moves a Google map (to add markers to the map), and it occurs if the user moves around too quickly.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
// Code located inside an external JS file referenced inside the head
// Not wrapped inside document.ready - but all the code setting up 
// the map (calling a function which calls a function which adds the 
// tilesloaded listener) *is* inside document.ready
function addMarkers() {
    var pm_url = "http://www.cyclestreets.net/api/photos.json?key=" + MY_KEY;
    $.ajax({
       url: pm_url,
       crossDomain: true, 
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       data: pmdata,
       jsonpCallback: 'photos',
       success: function(data) {
        // TBA
       },
       error: function() {
           alert("Sorry, error retrieving photos!");
       }
   });
}
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
 addMarkers(map);
 });
```

Having Googled a bit, the error `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'photos' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function` generally seems to occur when jQuery has not been loaded.

However, I don't see that this is relevant here, because the function is called from the map's tilesloaded event - and it doesn't generally fire the first time, it tends to fire after five or six rapid map resizes. So if it works once, the page surely can't have 'forgotten' about jQuery?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Try removing the line `jsonpCallback: 'photos',` and see if it works. Better to let jQuery handle those things. While you're at it, do you really need the `contentType` parameter set like that? That's for sending data, not receiving it...

Comment: it just means photos is not a function/method therefore you have not supplied a callback, so somewhere you should have `function photos(){...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify the *name* of the function that jQuery creates from your `success` handler, but not actually define *a separate function to use*, [you should use `jsonp: 'photos'` instead of `jsonpCallback: photos`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  Currently it's using `photos` in the URL which means it's calling `photos({ ...data... })` when the JSONP response comes back, and that doesn't exist.  Using the [`jsonp` option on `$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) would create it.  You have a few options here.

You can do this (in a global scope) either of these two ways:

```
function addMarkers() {
    var pm_url = "http://www.cyclestreets.net/api/photos.json?key=" + MY_KEY;
    $.ajax({
       url: pm_url,
       crossDomain: true, 
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       data: pmdata,
       jsonpCallback: 'photos',
       error: function() {
           alert("Sorry, error retrieving photos!");
       }
   });
}
function photos(data) {
    // TBA
}
```

Or, what you intended I think:

```
function addMarkers() {
    var pm_url = "http://www.cyclestreets.net/api/photos.json?key=" + MY_KEY;
    $.ajax({
       url: pm_url,
       crossDomain: true, 
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       data: pmdata,
       jsonp: 'photos',
       success: function(data) {
        // TBA
       },
       error: function() {
           alert("Sorry, error retrieving photos!");
       }
   });
}
```

....or just leave both off and let jQuery name the `success` callback itself (this happens by default, based on a timestamp).

Comment: Thank you! I was confused, clearly :-/ This solves the problem.

Comment: This will cause cache-busting because the url will change everytime. This isn't a problem if your queries are dynamic anyway.   http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2010/03/12/avoiding-rate-limits-and-getting-banned-in-yql-and-pipes-caching-is-your-friend/